# Host static Wordpress blog on S3?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3

I have an old WordPress blog that I no longer use but want to keep the pages to support old incoming links. Right now I pay $20/mo for a t1.micro instance on EC2 just to run the stupid thing. I decided to use the [Really Static](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/really-static/) plugin to extract the entire site in to static content with the goal to host it on S3's ability to host [root domain content](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/12/27/root-domain-support-on-amazon-s3-hosted-websites/).

The good news is that the static export worked great. The bad news is that my URLs never used "clean URLs" and so the pages were stuff like `http://example.com/blog/?p=123`. The way the plugin works is that it exports a directory such as `p=123` and then puts an `index.html` file in it.

My question is: does anyone have a bright idea on how (or if) I can host a URL like `/blog/?p=123` and serve it from S3 using the static content I have? Even when I create a directory in S3 of `?p=123` I can only get `/blog/%3Fp%3D123/index.html` to serve while `/blog/?p=123/index.html` shows an access denied error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.slowping.com/index.html%3Fp=76.html discusses converting a wordpress blog to s3.

As you can see from the url, he's using the p= style of url.  He seems to be using the directions from http://mossiso.com/2007/09/10/converting-wordpress-to-static-html.html though, so it may be that you just need to use a different converter.

Followup: Here's an article that discusses converting a custom themed wordpress install to octopress and it discusses some edge cases that may be relevant.

http://mrdanadams.com/2012/migrating-wordpress-custom-theme-octopress-jekyll/#.UUJxNltxuGo